# What kind of garage flooring is this?

Tags: concrete, flooring, garage

I like the flooring here in this picture but wonder what it is

[image]

Is it some paint / stain on top of concrete? Because I can see the crack.

Or is it some laminate plastic thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like an epoxy floor coating. Quikrete, Drylock, and Rust-Oleum have products, probably many other specialist coating and concrete manufacturers do as well (I have a can of Quikrete's version kicking around somewhere that I got from a friend who overbought it, but I haven't gotten around to putting it down yet. Can't really help beyond identification).

Comment: It does look like Epoxy from here https://www.quikrete.com/productlines/garage-floor-coating.asp. The crack is still very obvious even from photo far away.

Comment: @HP. If you read the installation manuals for epoxy floors, they all say that any cracks should be filled before installation.  The number one thing people do when installing a floor like this is skimp on the prep work.  They might assume the floor is "clean enough" or that crack "is so small it will fill up".  Well, it isn't, and then the crack is extra visible forever.

Comment: Yeah I see bad (ie little to no) prep work causing finishes to fail or have notable defect all the time, especially when it comes to concrete. You should also water seal any surfaces that have a history of water seepage issues before applying any epoxy coating, not to mention etching the surface.